# Interface to list of objects design pattern?

Tags: java

I’m currently working on a project that Involves a list of employee objects. I generate this list by reading from a database of Employees using hibernate.

Now my question is that the current system simply passes about a List of employee objects but I’m not sure that’s the best way.

What I have done now is create an EmployeeManager object which is responsible for creating, removing, searching, and updating the list of employees.

Is this the best way? Or just another unneeded abstraction and it’s fine to pass a list?

Comment: Your description is much too vague for us to give you an advice. Use what you think is the most readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you are doing is a kind of Repository pattern.

Use the Repository pattern to achieve one or more of the following objectives:

- You want to maximize the amount of code that can be tested with automation and to isolate the data layer to support unit testing.
- You access the data source from many locations and want to apply centrally managed, consistent access rules and logic.
- You want to implement and centralize a caching strategy for the data source.
- You want to improve the code's maintainability and readability by separating business logic from data or service access logic.
- You want to use business entities that are strongly typed so that you can identify problems at compile time instead of at run time.
- You want to associate a behavior with the related data. For example, you want to calculate fields or enforce complex relationships or business rules between the data elements within an entity.
- You want to apply a domain model to simplify complex business logic.
  Do consider UnitOfWork patten along with repository patten.

From :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649690(v=pandp.10)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.

But usually it is a good practice to create another abstraction layer and use that in further classes/implementations etc.

Why? Well, imagine you need to change your database layer with another technology for whatever reason; that would save you a lot of time, by just having to modify the mentioned layer.
But also, you should not abuse and make too many layers. It really depends on certain situations and you should chose the best approach for you.

There are a lot of resources in this area of "how should I write my code".

- R.C. Martin - Clean code
- R.C. Martin – Agile Software Development. Principles Patterns and Practices
- E. Gamma, R. Helm, R. Johnson, J.
  Vlissides - Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented
  Software

I would recommend you read some and make your own opinions. Some situations may require compromises.